# Wireless Adapter

Tags: adapter

So I just discovered that the wireless adapter I have for my PC is windows exclusive. But I've heard that you can use ndsiwrapper to get a Linux compatible driver for it. Does anyone know how to do this? The adapter I'm using is the SeoJack AC600Mbps Dual Band USB wifi adapter. Model number: SJ-AC600WX
When I do the `lsusb` terminal command this is the output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e6f:011f Logic3 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's worth saying what your adapter actually is.

Comment: SeoJack AC600Mbps Dual Band USB wifi adapter. Model number:   SJ-AC600WX

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command with the adapter inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and you could have probably found out through the "Search Q&A" box in the upper right corner, just above the "Ask Question" button, which you found.

I asked my Ubuntu 14.04.5 stystem, thusly:

```
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-cache search ndiswrapper
ndisgtk - graphical frontend for ndiswrapper (installation of Windows WiFi drivers)
ndiswrapper-common - Common scripts required to use the utilities for ndiswrapper
ndiswrapper-dkms - Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module (DKMS)
ndiswrapper-source - Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module
ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 - Userspace utilities for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module
```

There is no claim of functionality, since you didn't disclose any information more than "wireless adapter I have for my PC"

Comment: SeoJack AC600Mbps Dual Band USB wifi adapter. Model number: SJ-AC600WX

Comment: ndiswraper will not work because it is a new adapter.